# Liferay Autologin: Mapping users vs add user to Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Please, can you give me your opinion about this issue?

I've done an Autologin which is authenticating the username and password against my legacy system.

Once I've verified the user, I have two choices:

1. Add the user  (if it does not exist) to Liferay ( and assign groups ) 
   or
2. Map the verified user against 3 or 4 liferay users.

If my database is about 10.000 users, but I only have 3 or 4 roles, I thought the second choice would be better, but, what happens then with the welcome message once the user is logged with the liferay user credentials?

Comment: What do you mean by "Map the verified user against 3 or 4 liferay users."?

Comment: I only need 3 or 4 diferent kind of users, for instance ADMIN_USER, OWNER_USER, AGENCY_USER. All my users should map to one of these users in liferay. My Database could have thousands of users, but always with one role described above.  So, should I create all these users to liferay or can I use only 4 Liferay users to login to the system? My Autologin could add the user or get an existing liferay user (mapping). I hope it is clearer now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan,

You need to create all the users in liferay because while login either we use the screenName or emailAdress(which must be unique and exsits in DB) ,also before login we can't check what role is assigned to user and we can't fetch the user of same role from the liferay(probably it will effect the security measures of liferay).About the welcome message it's managed by theme (velocity template) which use the name of current loggeIn user,it can't be managed, so we can't show different name with the same user  login on the basis of role.

Thanks